# Does an Angularjs E2E scenario test have access to GET parmeters?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-e2e

I am using the `runner.html` E2E test file to do integration testing on an Angular project.

```
//In runner.html
<script src="scenarios.js"></script>

//In this scenarios.js file, we have some code like this: 
describe('App', function() {
  pauseAll = false;
  it('Testing index.html', function() {
      ....
      if (pauseAll) pause();
  });
```

This javascript code allows us to just change the `pauseAll` variable at the top of the file when we want to manually review every page that is being loaded during the test.

My question: how can I make pauseAll equal to true if the GET parmeter pauseAll is passed in via the runner.html url? For example:

```
../test/e2e/runner.html?pauseAll=true
```

Answer (score 0):

As easy as

```
pauseAll = window.location.search.replace( "?pauseAll=", "" );
```